# Can I program for Raspberry Pi Pico without having a real board?

Tags: software-recommendation

Are there any options to code and learn Raspberry Pi Pico **without real hardware?** I have used simulators online for Arduino UNO as well as ATTiny85 in the past.

Do they support Arduino style coding? I will be then able to program the real hardware as soon as I will be able to receive it!
Please forgive me if this is not the right forum to ask about Raspberry Pi Pico

Comment: In answer to one of those questions, pretty sure that there is a pi pico profile available for the arduino IDE.

Comment: A web search shows https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/program-raspberry-pi-pico-with-arduino-ide I expect there are plenty of answers.

Comment: Thanks! The link is not working. Is it working for you? I am also looking for no hardware solution, which I think might not be this

Comment: Sorry, I do not know when it stopped working. There should be plenty of others.  Also see https://blog.arduino.cc/2021/04/27/arduino-mbed-core-for-rp2040-boards/

Comment: this is the right Q&A site to ask about the Raspberry Pi Pico .... your question is not about the Raspberry Pi Pico

Comment: @jsotola - what do you mean it is "not about the Raspberry Pi Pico"? I see the question is "Can I program for Raspberry Pi Pico", how is that not about Raspberry Pi Pico?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the forum. your question is poorly researched as I can find on Google with a simple search a few options.
Does a google search show many options on the first page? Did you try searching first?

---

https://www.reddit.com/r/microcontrollers/comments/lrwvka/do_you_know_any_good_simulators_for_raspberry_pi/

> There doesn't seem to be an official option like with Arduino and
> TinkerCAD, so I'm just looking for whatever works. I know that
> u/SpaceMan_The has already [created a model of the Pico on Flux.ai](https://www.flux.ai/vasy_skral/raspberry-pi-pico-rev3-board-schematic), but
> that system is still in beta and doesn't seem very easy to use. Plus
> the model I linked is all in separate pieces, and when I tried to fork
> it and assemble the pieces, I couldn't get it to work how I wanted...
>
> Paul Falstad's Circuit Simulator Applet seems really easy to use, but
> I can't find a way to add PIO, and I need that for what I'm trying to
> test.

---

https://hackaday.io/project/177082-raspberry-pi-pico-emulator

There is [minimal documentation](https://docs.wokwi.com/parts/wokwi-pi-pico) and four examples only for the Pico simulator? is that what you would expect. I was able to run [some examples](https://docs.wokwi.com/parts/wokwi-pi-pico#simulator-examples) but you should dive deeper and see which one suits you best.

https://github.com/GitJer/Some_RPI-Pico_stuff/tree/main/state_machine_emulator

---

https://github.com/GitJer/Some_RPI-Pico_stuff/tree/main/state_machine_emulator

> Emulator of a Raspberry Pi Pico PIO state machine What does it do
>
> This code takes a .pio.h file generated by pioasm as input and
> emulates how a PIO state machine would execute it. The intended
> purpose is to gain insight in how it works to find bugs.
>
> Besides the .pio.h file, there are two more input files:
>
> ```
> a file describing the c-statements such as putting data into the Tx FIFO (c_program)
> a file describing the externally driven GPIO pins (pin_program)
> ```
>
> The user can obtain insights into the workings of the pio code through
> a GUI which shows all (?) the relevant sm internal data such as
> registers.
>
> For now this code only supports one state machine, of one PIO running
> one program. Workflow
>
> When working on a project, I typically have an IDE (in my case vscode)
> with the project files, the pin_program and c_program files opened.
> Additionally, I have the emulator open with the .pio.h file of the
> project
>
> When changing the .pio code, I use the IDE function 'build' to have
> pioasm generate a new .pio.h file. Then I press Reload in the
> emulator, and study the emulation output. When changing the c-code
> that uses the pio code, I have to decide if the c_program also needs
> to change. Often, this will not be the case because the c_program and
> pin_program act more like test cases than that they mimic the real
> c-code or real signals applied to the pins. Why?
>
> The problem with the RPi Pico PIO state machines (sm) is that
> debuggers do not give the insight I need when writing code for a sm. I
> typically write some code, upload it to the pico and find that it
> doesn't do what I want it to do. Instead of guessing what I do wrong,
> I would like to see the values of e.g. the registers when the sm is
> executing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Wokwi supports multiple types of microcontrollers, including the pico: https://wokwi.com/projects/new/pi-pico

They have the full details, including what the simulation does and doesn't support, here: https://docs.wokwi.com/parts/wokwi-pi-pico

Be aware that they warn that they currently do not have accurate analog simulation for the circuit.